# Почему Coroutine не выполняет ожидание с Action параметром. UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть абстрактный класс который наследуют и реализуют другие классы, в этих классах я  вызываю публичный метод абстрактного класса который возвращает `IEnumerator`, его сигнатура:

```
    public IEnumerator ActionAfterDelay(float seconds, Action action)
```

Планируется что он должен выполнять `action` после `seconds`. В итоге я при вызове данного метода не получаю первый **`Debug.Log`**, и получает сразу выполнение действия и в консоле появляется второй **`Debug.Log`**. То есть я пропускаю данное ожидание, и не понимаю почему это происходит. Вот сам метод из абстрактного класса

```
    public IEnumerator ActionAfterDelay(float seconds, Action action)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Wait before Action {seconds} seconds");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);

        action.Invoke();
        // пробовал и просто вызвать action(); - безуспешно

        Debug.Log("Action TIME!");
    }
```

Вот вызов данного метода из наследуемого класса, он вызывается в `switch`:

```
    case SimpleInfluenceEffectType.Explosion:

        StartCoroutine(ActionAfterDelay(0.25f, () =>
        {
            if (Target.CurrentGameObject.TryGetComponent(out EnemyState enemyState))
            {
                if (enemyState.IsDontExplode)
                {
                    VisualEffect.Instance.InstantiateEffect(
                        Target.UnitState.transform.position,
                        VisualEffect.EffectType.ExplosionShield,
                        Target.UnitState.transform.transform,
                        true);

                    return;
                }
            }

            VisualEffect.Instance.InstantiateEffect(Target.UnitState.transform.position, VisualEffect.EffectType.MobExplosion);

            Target.UnitState.TakeDamage(EffectValue, gameObject);
        }));

        break;
```

Я где то ошибаюсь, и не могу найти решение

Comment: В абстрактном классе метод надо пометить как `abstract` если у него нет тела или как `virtual` если есть, а в наследниках как `override`. Чтобы вызвать метод базового класса явно в обход метода наследника, надо вызвать его через префикс `base.ИмяМетода()`.

Comment: Это если вызывать метод не в наследнике, я же вызываю его в наследнике и не хочу его переопределять, я долгое время не понимал почему он код не работал, и у меня (возможно не только) случается моменты когда визуал студио не отправляет изменения в юнити или в файл, не знаю как быть точнее, и я корректировал код как бы в никуда, файл не изменялся соответственно юнити использовал старый код где нет этой строчки, только после перезапуска юнити и переписывания данной строчки заного у меня всё заработало. Юнити вот так вот меня иногда подставляет ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код рабочий, всё выполняет, вот только Визуал студио не записывал мои изменения в коде, и юнити использовал старый код где нет использования данного метода, от этого ничего и не происходило, есть много вопросов почему логи отправлялись, но всё это было решение перезапуском визуал студио и переписыванием кода.